# how to grouping and sorting by period in mysql

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I want to group and sort data in mysql.

| itemName | startDate(Int) | endDate(Int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 20221101 | 20221110 |
| item2 | 20221101 | 20221120 |
| item3 | 20221101 | 20221231 |
| item4 | 20221201 | 20221231 |
| item5 | 20221220 | 20231231 |
| item6 | 20230101 | 20231231 |

I want to sort data like 'in progress => planned => overdue' by today

for example,

if today is 2022-11-11, I expect the sort would be
`item2 => item3 => item4 => item5 => item6 => item1(overdue)`

If today is 2022-12-01, I expect the sort would be
`item3 => item4 => item5 => item6 => item1(overdue) => item2(overdue)`

If today is 2023-01-01, I expect the sort would be
`item6(in progress) => item1 => item2 => item3 => item4 => item5`

Do I have to use Group by? I don't know how to sorting these data.

please let me know how to groupby and sorting in mysql or sequelize.js

I just use item in progress below. but I want to add endItem, PlannedItem

```js
  let items = await Items.findAll({
        where: {
          endDate: { [Op.gte]: date },
          startDate: { [Op.lte]: date },
        },

       })
```

I thought that
`in progress item` is `startDate <= today <= endDate`,
`planned item` is `today < startDate`,
`overdue item` is  `endDate < today`

and after making 3 groups, sorting... but I don't know how to solve it..

Comment: how do you want them sorted within your three categories?  (e.g. what determines the relative order of the in progress items, etc)

Comment: what datatype are startDate/endDate?

Comment: hello! what determines the relative order of the progress is today.
and datataype of startDate/endDate is integer

Comment: I mean if you have two items that are e.g. in progress today, how do you want to determine which comes first?

Comment: if I have two items in progress, I think early StartDate comes first. for example, if items's startDate are 20221201, 20221203, I think items should be 20221201 -> 20221203 in order.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want:

```
order by
    case
        when itemName like 'progress%' then 1
        when itemName like 'planned%' then 2
        when itemName like 'end%' then 3
    end,
    0+regexp_substr(itemName, '\\d+$')
```

I think in sequelize you'd need to put all that in an `order: sequelize.literal(...)`

group by something you only use when combining multiple rows (or combinations of joined rows) into fewer result rows, which doesn't sound like the case here.

Comment: this is a very neat answer on performing custom group and sort!

Comment: Thanks to reply! but my intention was that I wanted to sort items by today. 

for example, if today is 2023.01.01,  5 items are overdue. so I expect the sort will be 'planned2, end1, end2, progress1, progress2, planned1'.

Comment: I think people get confused with my intention, so  I changed Items name